# I have a 401k loan used for a house down payment and now I am changing jobs: What should I do?

Tags: united-states, loans, small-business, solo-401k

I guess this could be a cautionary tale, but I am hoping it can be remedied.

I had a job that I am leaving, but I had took a 401k loan to put down on a house.  I don't have the money to pay it back so my idea was this.

Borrow the balance that I owe from a bank, roll over the replenished 401k to an individual 401k (through LLC I am establishing) and then take another 401k loan out again and then pay of the bank loan.  Can I open a individual 401k if I also have a full time job and the LLC will be on the side?  Any funds I contribute to the individual 401k will be after taxes.

or

Take the tax hit.

Comment: I'm a very similar situation. I can pay back most of it, but would deplete my savings to do so. I'm wondering if I can roll over to an IRA and borrow against that?

Comment: You can't do it via a IRA unless you are going to fake some house purchase, I chickened out on that because I don't want anyone I know to compromise themselves possibly or having IRS chase me.  Do an LLC, open a individual 401k with etrade and voila.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step is to contact the company you are considering using as an administrator. Ask if they have a loan provision. 
For what it's worth, I looked at [Schwab](http://www.schwab.com/public/schwab/investment_products/retirement/business_retirement/individual_401k), and it seems to indicate they do not offer loans against this type of 401(k). That doesn't mean no one does, just that you may need to look around.

Comment: I have found sharebuilder, etrade, and merrill lynch offers a 401k loan for indivduals.

Comment: So you've done the research already? That's great. You can have an employer 401(k) at the same time as the individual. Your total deposit is still subject to the $16500 limit, plus profit sharing or matching.

Comment: For others, I did this using etrade after I setup a LLC.  It was fairly painless, just wish I knew this a long time ago.